# crontab on GENTOO : how to make it run?

Tags: linux, cron, gentoo

Logged as root, in **gentoo** linux distrib.

crontab -e

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/www/crons/crontab.php
```

crontab -l

lists me the job.

When running manually in SSH.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/www/crons/crontab.php
```

everything works fine.

But cron is NEVER called by crontab : what is wrong ?

Comment: Off-topic. Also, is the cron daemon running? Did you add it to all necessary runlevels?

Comment: Check with `ps ax | grep cron` or with systemd `systemctl cron.service status` to confirm it is running.

Comment: Please go through the steps on the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) and report your findings

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a blank line at the end of the crontab. This is mandatory! If your last line is anything else, but a blank line, cron for some reason does not work.

So the crontab is build like this:

- (Optional) Comments beginning with #
- The actual lines you want to execute
- blank line

As mentioned in the comments: make sure the crontab is running.